# Use loop do to creat a text menu in a method

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm really new in Ruby.

So I did make one menu in the loop, that send me to "start.menu_one" but can I make another loop in the "def menu_one" that can send me to "def menu_three"

The problem is I can't run the code? Do any of you know what the problem is, because I can't find it.

```
file = File.new(".txt", "a")


class Start

  def menu_one 

    while (select !=2)  
    puts "Press 1 to make a new test"
    puts "Press 2 to search after test results"
    if (select == 1)
      start.menu_three
      break
    elsif (select == 2) # its here the problem is? 
    end

  def menu_two
    puts "Press 1 to see the overview of the tests"
  end
end

  def menu_three
    puts "hej"
  end
end 

  start = Start.new
  require 'io/console'
  select = 0


  puts "Welcome to the multiple choice test"

  while (select !=3)
    puts "Press 1 to login as admin"
      puts "\n"
    puts "Press 2 to login as student"
      puts "\n"
    puts "Press 3 to exit "
      puts "\n"
    select = STDIN.getch.to_i 

    if (select == 1)
    start.menu_one
    break

  elsif (select == 2)

    start.menu_two
    break 

  elsif (select == 3)
    puts "You have now exited the program"
    abort
  end

end 
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of your code, and a clear description of what you're trying to achieve (and why it's not working)? What is `start`? How are `menu_one` and `menu_three` defined? (Is there a `menu_two`?!)

Comment: @TomLord I have just updatet my question and sorry still pretty new in this

Comment: Your code is broken in multiple ways... It needs significant restructuring to even execute. `select` is a name collision with a [built-in method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-select), you should use another name; `loop do (condition)` should be `while(condition) do`; and you're trying to reference variables all over the place without passing them into the methods.

Comment: For example, how is `Start#method_one` supposed to know the value of `select`? Unless you make it a global variable (don't!), it needs to be passed in as a parameter to the method.

Comment: @TomLord dont quite sure I understand you, if you take out the start.menu_three the code works fine until you get to the menu_two?

Comment: So you'e changed the code significantly since my last comment... But it's still very much broken, in many ways. You're defining `menu_one` *inside* the definition of `menu_two` (fix the indentation, and it becomes much easier to see!); you're still not passing variables around; your code still raises the above mentioned error: "'select': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..4) (ArgumentError)"; ...

Comment: I advise you to scrap this for now, and start on something smaller and simpler. There are so many issues that it basically needs to be re-written anyway. Why not start with a simple method definition *that takes in some parameters*, so you can learn the basics of passing arguments to a method?

Comment: "I can't run the code?" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve] with a focus on *minimal*. You shouldn't really need 43 lines to demonstrate your problem, I'm willing to bet 3-4 lines are more than enough.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So the code should end out to be a program that include this:
Admins should be able to:
- create a new multiple choice test
- view test results for each student (the specific answers and the score)

Student users should able to
- take the test and get a test score
- view his/her own answers

I'm just trying to get all the differents menus to work right now

Comment: You still haven't told us what the problem is with your code. "I can't run the code?" is not a precise enough problem statement that we would be able to help you. It isn't even a statement *at all*, it is a *question* … how should we know whether you can run the code? Is there an error message? If yes, what does it say? Where does it occur? Under what conditions does it occur? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ?

Comment: Can you narrow down the problematic code some more? I highly doubt it requires over 40 lines of code to demonstrate the problem, usually about 3-4 lines are enough.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, okay I will try to be more specific. When I run the program and presses 1 to "login as admin" it says: 

/Users/frederikstubbe/Documents/Ruby/ITeksamen.rb:8:in `select': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4) (ArgumentError)
from /Users/frederikstubbe/Documents/Ruby/ITeksamen.rb:8:in `menu_one'
from/Users/frederikstubbe/Documents/Ruby/ITeksamen.rb:55:in`<class:Start>'
from /Users/frederikstubbe/Documents/Ruby/ITeksamen.rb:4:in `<main>'


If I take away the " start.menu_three" is working finte. But I want to be able to go in the Method menu_three from the method menu_one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry I'm really new at Ruby, only got like 6 lessons in school and still trying to learn

Comment: Frederikstubbe, I already told you why this error is appearing. Twice. You are not passing a variable to the method, and your variable name conflicts with another built-in ruby method.

Comment: @TomLord how do I pass the variable to the method?

Comment: @Frederikstubbe `def method_one(var1, var2, ...)`. Honestly, my advice would be to park this project for now and start by reading some beginners programming guides (e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm) or even follow some basic tutorials (e.g. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Start

  def menu_one 

    while (select !=2)  
    puts "Press 1 to make a new test"
    puts "Press 2 to search after test results"
    if (select == 1)
      start.menu_three
      break
    elsif (select == 2) # its here the problem is? 
    end

  def menu_two
    puts "Press 1 to see the overview of the tests"
  end
end

  def menu_three
    puts "hej"
  end
end 

  start = Start.new
  require 'io/console'
  select = 0


  puts "Welcome to the multiple choice test"

  while (select !=3)
    puts "Press 1 to login as admin"
      puts "\n"
    puts "Press 2 to login as student"
      puts "\n"
    puts "Press 3 to exit "
      puts "\n"
    select = STDIN.getch.to_i 

    if (select == 1)
    start.menu_one
    break

  elsif (select == 2)

    start.menu_two
    break 

  elsif (select == 3)
    puts "You have now exited the program"
    abort
  end

end 
end
```

Comment: I've edited your code to be more readible.  SO renders code blocks as everything with 4 spaces before.  There is a little button `{ }` that does code formatting.
Additionally, please add some explanation.  SO frowns on code-only answers.
Happy contributing, and welcome to SO!